# Customize Project path and name in STM32CubeMX

Tags: stm32, iar, stm32cubemx

Consider a `CubeMX` project where you have configured the STM32F103 microcontroller and have chosen EWARM as the main IDE/Toolchain. When generating code, if you select the Application Structure to advance, you may encounter the following directory structure:

```
YourPrjName:
|--Core
|--Driver
|--EWARM
|CubePrj.ioc
|.mxproject
```

Now, let's say you want to place both the `Core` and `Driver` folders inside another folder named `BSW`, and generate the Cube project related files in a different location. The updated directory structure would look like this:

```
YourPrjName:
|--BSW
|  |__Core
|  |--Driver
|--EWARM
|--CubePrj
|  |--CubePrj.ioc
|  |--.mxproject
```

In this revised structure, the Core and Driver folders are located within the `BSW` folder, and the Cube project files placed under the `CubePrj` directory.

How this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STM32CubeMX might not give you the flexibility you need for you to customize your project tree layout. The only option offered for the Code Generator is *"Generate peripheral initialization as a pair of '.c/.h' files per peripheral"* and that is it.

IAR provides a small utility named [EWPtool](https://github.com/iarsystems/project-migration-tools) which can not only (re)populate an existing project based on a folder selection with its sources but also can update references in the preprocessor paths to the header files accordingly.

It is possible to use the utility from the command line with this parameter syntax:

[image: The GUI Error shows the parameter right order]

But for that you need to make sure you have the file `EWARM\settings\YourPrjName.cfg` with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EWPtool>
  <selectedPath>$PROJ_DIR$\..\..</selectedPath>
</EWPtool>
```

And then, after moving folders around, you run `EWPtool` from the project's `EWARM` folder:

```
EWPtool . YourPrjName YourPrjName
```

Their official repository contains extra use case examples which might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've never try for .ioc and .mxproject but for your drivers and Core you can just create a new folder and move them in to it. You may have to change path in properties of your project -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols.

Be careful, to move your C file in a folder, you need to create source folder